# How to estimate significance based on a level of categorical variable

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, interaction

I have data with 3 columns: `y` represents dependent continuous variable, `xcont` represents independent continuous variable, `xcat` represents independent categorical variable with 3 levels: `xcat1`, `xcat2`, and `xcat3`.
I am doing simple model with interaction:

```
y = xcont + xcat + xcon*xcat
```

The statistical software I am using (in my case, R) shows the standard table with coefficients, standard errors and p-values, respectively, like this (using made up numbers for simplicity):

```
xcont 5 (2) 0.05

xcat1 10 (2) 0.02

xcat2 18 (1.5) 0.01

...
```

Now, I see that `xcont` is significant. But it is significant for the full model (with `xcat3` used as reference level for categorical variable `xcat`).

Is there a way I could explore significance of `xcont` for specific levels of `xcat`? I.e. estimate the coefficient and standard error?
For example, I would like to conclude something like "conditioning on `xcat1`, `xcont` is significant at *this* level".

It seems like the simplest solution is to do the regression of:

```
y = xcont + xcat1 + xcont*xcat1
```

Is there a "smarter" way though?

Comment: You should have 6 estimated regression coefficients. Apart from 3 you listed, other 3 are: intercept, xcont*xcat1, and xcont*xcat2.

Comment: You are looking for "simple main effects," and yes, the "smarter" way includes variance from the entire sample—this is precisely what simple main effects analyses are. There are guides on how to do it in SPSS, R, SAS, etc. if you Google for "simple main effects."